# Linking error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on OSX

Tags: macos, gcc, x86-64

The following is returned when trying to compile part of a project under OSX:

```
gcc -g -pipe -L/Projects/export buf_test.o buf.o -framework CoreFoundation -o buf_test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___assert_rtn", referenced from:
      _init in buf.o
      _get in buf.o
      _put in buf.o
  "___sprintf_chk", referenced from:
      _test in buf_test.o
  "___strcpy_chk", referenced from:
      _test_data_copy in buf_test.o
      ___inline_strcpy_chk in buf_test.o
  "_exit", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
  "_printf", referenced from:
      _test in buf_test.o
  "_puts", referenced from:
      _test in buf_test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Consider replacing `gcc` with `gcc -v -Wall` to understand more what is happening....

Comment: I ran into this today due to a 3rd party component being compiled without the min OS X version (e.g. "-mmacosx-version-min=10.7"). This previously worked before Mavericks/Xcode 5 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a library naming conflict with the standard libraries -- I had a library called libSystem.a in /Projects/export which was masking libSystem.dylib from being found.